# CMS martial arts membership management or own?

Tags: content-management-system

While I found quite some interesting suggestions on this site (the typical WP vs. Joomla) I just couldn't find an answer that could help me get started.

I know this is close to some of the other CMS questions but I'm missing specificities that need answering.

I'm looking for a CMS that can provide me with the following key functionalities, either through minimal programming or additional plugin installations. I'm stating this because it won't be just me, who can program, but also other trainers who are not technically inclined that will handle the site (in the future).

The functionalities I'm looking for:

- Schedule management of training
- Trainees of the club must check-in before or after the training to proof attendance, thus site must be mobile friendly. This is more proof-of-concept since not everyone has/wants a smartphone.
- Each trainee has his own profile that logs said attendance
- Possibility to provide feedback on training. For example: give a thumbs up on the last training, give a "yellow card" if the trainee misbehaved, two/three/four and you're prohibited from training ones/twice/thrice.
- The attendance allows the trainee to become eligible for the next exam
- Schedule management of said exam
- Yearly subscription reminders for the trainees and if under-aged required parent information
- Management of trainee profiles and subscriptions

Is the above possible through a CMS or is it too specific and will I need to program this myself? Either is fine by me but I'd first like to find out if a CMS can offer this.

Comment: So there is nobody that got any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to Go for a custom solution using ReactJS. 
There are very good open-source solutions for the admin part and the open/client part is fairly simple so React is perfect for what I want to achieve. Additionally, it also challenges to think differently since I never worked with ReactJS before.

With ReactJS I have a lot of freedom in how I implement the above scenarios while at the same time have a lot of support available online in cause of issues.